# Target an Element within another Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, logic

I'm looking to try to find an element inside another element then add an ID to it as this is a multi dynamic paged Prince document, so far I have the code below but unsure of how to check if the `title__container-page` DIV is inside the `page-first` DIV, as there'as more than one `page-first` element, I only want to add the ID to any `page-first` element that contains the `title__container-page` element, at the moment it's adding that ID to all of them.

```
<script>
    var checkedValue = "title__container-page";
    var targetModule = document.getElementsByClassName('page-first');

    var checkedArray = checkedValue.split(" ");             

    console.log(checkedArray);

    checkedArray.forEach(function (val, key) {
        if (val === "") {
            checkedArray.splice(key, 1)
        }
        if (checkedArray.length > 0) {
            targetModule[key].id = "column-padding-top";
        }
    }) 
</script>
```

Comment: Where does the code at Question check for an element?

Comment: you code does not do what you say it does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target an element inside another element you can use [`queryselector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

```js
var span = document.querySelector("#whatever .something");
span.id = "newId";

console.log(document.getElementById('newId'));
```

```html
<div id=whatever>
  <span class=something></span>
</div>
```

If you want to do it the long way you can change the context of `getElementsByClassName`.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("whatever");
var span = div.getElementsByClassName("something")[0];
span.id = "newId";

console.log(document.getElementById('newId'));
```

```html
<div id=whatever>
  <span class=something></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here are 5 parent divs with class='page-first', 3 of them containing child divs with class='title__container-page':**

```
<div class='page-first'>
    <div class='title__container-page'></div>
</div>

<div class='page-first'>
    <div class='title__container-page'></div>
</div>

<div class='page-first'>

</div>

<div class='page-first'>

</div>

<div class='page-first'>
    <div class='title__container-page'></div>
</div>
```

Inspect Element:

[image]

**The following scans over all parent divs, and adds an ID to the parent found to have a child with class='title__container-page':**

```
$('.page-first').each(function() {
      this_childs = $(this).children();
      this_childs.each(function() {
            if($(this).attr('class') == 'title__container-page') {
                add_id = 'div_' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1);
                $(this).parent().attr('id', add_id);  // add id to page-first element 
        }
      })
})
```

Inspect Element:

[image]

This is assuming you can use jQuery.